# Can't uninstall a package using npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

Why is `npm uninstall -g` not uninstalling a package?

```
$ which flourish
/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.3.0/bin/flourish
$ which npm
/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.3.0/bin/npm
$ npm uninstall -g flourish
up to date in 0.056s
$ flourish
  No command specified. Type ‘flourish help’ for help.
```

Local uninstall doesn't help either:

```
$ npm uninstall flourish
up to date in 1.266s
$ flourish
  No command specified. Type ‘flourish help’ for help.
```

Update - after doing the above:

```
$ npm -g ls --depth=0
/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.3.0/lib
...
├── @flourish/sdk@3.6.0
├── @mapbox/geojson-area@0.2.2
├── @mapbox/geojson-merge@1.0.2
```

Comment: Well, I managed to uninstall it by doing `npm uninstall -g @flourish/sdk@next` - but that was a lucky guess. Next time, how can I know what the correct package name is?

Comment: You cannot uninstall something you don't know a correct name for. If you forgot package name which an executable belongs to, take a look at executable internals.

Comment: ok, thanks! that's quite confusing.